# electronic circuit used in A to A USB data transfer cable

Tags: embedded

Which processing element/bridge electronic circuit used in A to A USB data transfer cable? with detailed explanation. I searches a lot but some where i found electronic bridge circuit is required and some said only A/A USB cable required.

**Can anyone clearly tell me what is the need for A to A USB data transfer?**

Comment: The need for USB-A to USB-A tansfer us not to use USB at all, as that is not defined by the standard.

Comment: This is not a programming related question, so not appropriate to SO. Such a circuit would need to present a USB device to the two hosts, and transfer data between them. Two back-to-back FTDI serial-to-USB devices for example would do that, and look just like a serial cable. However Ethernet would probably be simpler, and faster.